# To show that the annulus $\{x \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 < ||x|| < 2\}$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

To show that the annulus $\{x \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 < ||x|| < 2\}$ is connected.

I want to do it without path-connectedness or polygon-connectedness using the fact continuous image of a connected set is connected.

What will be a suitable function to be defined?

Comment: Use the function $e^z=(e^x\cos(y),e^x\sin(y))$ and the set $[2,\ln(2)]\times\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$Q=[0,2\pi]\times (1,2)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is connected set and $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $f(\theta,r)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ is continuous.

Comment: will not be it $(1,2)$ instead of closed $[1,2]$

Comment: @joymath: Yes, you're right.